# Karate Intuit: How to validate dynamic json array

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

I've been using karate for sometime, but I've gotten stuck on how to validate this dynamic array. Array apple varies in size when I hit the API.

How do I go through the array one by one and validate the prices?

JSON:

```
  {
    "data": {
        "apple": [
            {
                "a": 0,
                "price": 1970,
                "date": "2018-05-30"
            },
            {
                "a": 1,
                "price": 1266,
                "date": "2018-05-31"
            },
            {
                "a": 2,
                "price": 1422,
                "date": "2018-06-01"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status_code": 200
}
```

Comment: Karthik, were you able to figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I am able to do this by data driven approach https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

```
Feature: my test

Scenario: 
    * def response =
      """
      {
          "data": {
              "apple": [
                  {
                      "a": 0,
                      "price": 1970,
                      "date": "2018-05-30"
                  },
                  {
                      "a": 1,
                      "price": 1266,
                      "date": "2018-05-31"
                  },
                  {
                      "a": 2,
                      "price": 1422,
                      "date": "2018-06-01"
                  }
              ]
          },
          "status_code": 200
      }
      """
    * def va = call read('classpath:karate/examples/Assertions.feature') response.data.apple
```

In Assertions.feature file my code is :

```
Scenario: 
    * match __arg contains { a: '#(__arg.a)', price: '#(__arg.price)', date: '#(dataBaseResult[__loop].date)' }
```

**Note:**

1. Expected data can be pulled from any source. Example: Data Base
2. Remember '__loop' will give index of array

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the [`match each`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-each) syntax ?

```
* def response = 
"""
{
    "data": {
        "apple": [
            {
                "a": 0,
                "price": 1970,
                "date": "2018-05-30"
            },
            {
                "a": 1,
                "price": 1266,
                "date": "2018-05-31"
            },
            {
                "a": 2,
                "price": 1422,
                "date": "2018-06-01"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status_code": 200
}
"""
* match each response.data.apple == { a: '#? _ < 3', price: '#number', date: '#regex \\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}'}
```

EDIT: if you are trying to do dynamic stuff, that's what Karate's JS interop can help with

```
# work on the second item in the array
* def index = 1
* def second = response.data.apple[index]
* match second.price = 1266
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for a quick answer, but the problem is I don't want to do a static validation. I have a function in java which will query the dB for a particular date and get the price(I know how to use this function in karate, but how do I do it for this dynamic sized array) , which is how I want to validate

Comment: @KarthikRavi I fail to see the issue. just use array indexes ? `* match response.data.apple[0]` and so on ?

Comment: Hey that's fine, but I don't want to do it one by one like * match response.data.apple[0] then after that * match response.data.apple[1] and so on. Is it possible to have a loop to go through the array and validate?

Comment: @KarthikRavi your question is extremely unclear, I'm sorry. but yes, you can do all kinds of insanity, why don't you go through the examples: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/sort-array.feature